# Colocar gif no Typewrite

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, gostaria de adicionar um gif a frente de um texto utilizando o efeito TypeWrite.

Código css:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Animação*/

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(13) 500ms infinite, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(13) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 160px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 160px;
  }
  90% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Animação*/

.anim-typewriters {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 500ms infinite, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 160px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 160px;
  }
  90% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line anim-typewriter">BigBlack</p>
```

O GIF ficaria ali a frente de onde está escrito *BigBlack* no `<p>` (html)
Assim ele iria escrevendo aos poucos a palavra *BigBlack* e depois colocaria o gif na frente.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara é só ajustar a largura da animação no `width` dentro do `@keyframes`, e depois colocar mais dois `steps` no `animation-steps` correspondendo ao imagem e o espaço e pronto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
 background-color: black;
 display: flex;
}
.line {
 position: relative;
 width: 0px;
 margin: auto;
 border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
 font-size: 180%;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;

}
/*Animação*/
.anim-typewriter {
 animation: typewriter 4s steps(15) 500ms infinite,
 blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(15) infinite normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter {
 0% {
  width: 0px;
 }
 10% {
  width: 0px;
 }
 25% {
  width: 280px;
 }
 75% {
  width: 280px;
 }
 90% {
  width: 0px;
 }
 100% {
  width: 0px;
 }
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
 from {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
 }
 to {
  border-right-color: transparent;
 }
}
```

```html
<p class="line anim-typewriter">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/36/36" alt=""> 
  BigBlack
</p>
```